# How to pass from Partizipialattribute to Relativsätze?

Tags: passive, relative-clause

I have some doubts how to turn a *Partizipialattribut* into a *Relativsatz.* **Is there any rule?** I know that I should use *werden* when the action is still in process and *sein* when the action is not in progress anymore, but it’s still unclear.

For example:

> ein schriftlich vereinbarter Liefertermin → ein Liefertermin, der schriftlich vereinbart ist/wird(?)

My questions:

1. Should I use *werden* or *sein*?
2. Can you tell me why?
3. Does it depend on the context?

Comment: I would say "ein Liefertermin,  der schriftlich vereinbart wurde" because the appointment was made in the past

Comment: I agree with @Iris, but “… ist” is also acceptable, because the appointment is still valid as long as the delivery date is in the future. Even “… wird” may be acceptable if it’s about the abstract concept of negotiating a delivery date, not a concrete act in the future (which “… werden wird” may be more appropriate for).

Comment: After @Crissov comment, I would say it depends on the context and on the meaning of the entire sentence...but that is simply my gut feeling (therefore only a comment and not an answer).

Comment: Both ;) „worden ist“

Answer (score 3):

It depends on whether you say it in an active or passive Kontext.

E.g.:

> ein Liefertermin, der schriftlich vereinbart wird

someone arranges the delivery date (right now)

> ein Liefertermin, der schriftlich vereinbart ist

being arranged is an attribute of the delivery date (at the moment)

You can use different tenses to specify when the statement is valid:

> ein Liefertermin, der schriftlich vereinbart wurde

the delivery date has been arranged at some point in the past